# using {%%} to make and variable in HTML document and replacing it using replace in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, api, openweathermap

I am creating a weather app which tells the weather of a particular location.

I have created variables i HTML file using {%temp%} this format and passing values from my index.js using `let temperature=tempVal.replace("{%tempval%}",orgVal.main.temp)`.

It is working fine for a single variable but when I add 3-4 replace commands it only replaces the last variable.

[Replace function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXc4L.png)
here only the last {%country%} gets replaced and other variables shows as follow.

[calling replace function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmWAu.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZ8rj.png)

Comment: https://github.com/RahulRudra81/WeatherMonitoring/tree/main  : github repo link

Comment: Please read [ask]; in particular the part about providing a [mcve] as *text* not as *pictures of text*. Also see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed.

Comment: [Please post code as formatted text rather than links to images of formatted text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Tangential: I'd suggest using an existing template engine, or at least use an object or map of keys/values for the replacements--easier in the long run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of, don't post screenshots/images of your code.

Coming to the problem, you are changing  the value `temperature` variable everytime when you try to replace string. That's why only the last line,i.e `country` gets replaced in the output.

What you need to do instead is chain your replace commands like this:

```
const replaceVal = (tempVal, orgVal) => {
    return tempVal.replace("{%tempval%}", orgVal.main.temp)
    .replace("{%tempmin%}", orgVal.main.temp_min)
    .replace("{%tempmax%}", orgVal.main.temp_max)
    .replace("{%location%}", orgVal.name)
    .replace("{%country%}", orgVal.sys.country)
};
```

Comment: Thankyou so much . It worked . And I am new to this community so sorry for posting the images.